# JS set properties of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

Is it safe to do `htmlElement.someProp = 'whatever including objects and other elements'` or could it lead to unexpected behaviour in different browsers?

Comment: no, it's not safe, there's a voodoo curse on everyone who does that

Comment: You have to use data-attribute for such situations <div data-some-prop="value">Test</div>

Comment: how about the specification as an answer?